# Odd prime combinatorics problem

Tags: combinatorics

How should I show that 
${2p \choose p}\equiv 2\pmod p$
if p is an odd prime!
help please

Comment: Do you know Wilson's theorem?

Comment: Try to use $\binom{2n}{n}=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}^2$.

Comment: Or the mod p Freshman's dream ? If so use $(x+y)^{2p} = [(x+y)^p]^2 \equiv (x^p +y^p)^2 \pmod p$, and compare coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{(p+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot2p}{p!}\equiv\frac{(p+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(p+(p-1))2}{(p-1)!}\equiv\frac{(p-1)!2}{(p-1)!}\equiv 2\pmod p$$

Answer (score 1):

By [Wolstenholme's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme's_theorem), for any prime $p>3$ we have:
$$ \binom{2p}{p}\equiv 2\pmod{p^\color{red}{3}}$$
hence the claim is trivial.